# Bones are invisible in blender

Tags: bones

When I move the camera around in Blender the bones instantly go invisible however when I press 1 they're visible.

[image: When I move camera]

[image: When I press 1]

Comment: I dont know if this is a bug or what

Comment: Since you are in ortho view the armature could be very far away from your object/center. With **armature** in outliner **selected** press Shift-S -> Cursor to Center, Shift-S -> Selection to Cursor.

Comment: Good call, from looking at the info dialogue that's displayed in the screen capture we can see that this is what's happening.  The 'y' position for the armature is 472 units.

Comment: @user2859 Could you add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @stacker, done.

Comment: @Joe if the answer was helpful, please consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing an object in axis aligned view, 
but not in user-defined view usually means it's far away from the current POV (point of view) or 
outside of the current frustum. Orthographic view provides no sense of depth. Objects appear the same 
size no matter how far or how close they are.

[image]

New objects are placed at the postion of the **3D Cursor**.

[image]

The 3D Cursor is placed with <kbd>LMB</kbd>. A click in empty space will position it in a plane, 
that is parallel to the view plane at the distance of its old position.

[image]

A click on a visible object will project the 3D cursor on the object.

[image]

The current cursor position and the position of the selected object are shown (and can be changed) 
in the **Properties Panel** of the **3D View**.

[image]

You can also use the **Snap** menu by pressing 
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

E.g. with the object selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> - **Cursor to Center**, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> - **Selection to Cursor** to set the objects position back to the center.

Answer (score 0):

It's layers. If you press 1, it's going to put you on the first layer. There are 10 layers, and 10 alternative layers. To access the layers, you can press 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 0. 
To access the alternative layers, you do the same thing but holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. You can select multiple layers by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing those numbers.

And for assign an object to a layer, you have to select the object and then hit <kbd>M</kbd>. You can select which layer you want it on from there. The layers on the top are the regular layers, and the layers on the bottom are the alternative layers.